# Как выводить числа, которые выводятся в экспоненциальной записи, в нормальном (десятичном) виде?

Tags: python, python-3.x, форматирование

Почему так числа отображаются: `7e-06 3e-06 4e-06`?

Как сделать вывод привычным, чтобы было удобней читать?

Если с большими значениями: `0.7 0.3 0.4,0.07 0.03 0.04, 0.0007 0.0003 0.0004`, то всё нормально, но со стотысячными долями: `7e-06 3e-06 4e-06`.

```
a = 0.000003
b = 0.000004
c = a + b
if a < b:
    print(c, a, b)
else:
    print(a)
```

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C

Comment: т.е как сделать нормальное не нормальным?

Comment: Да, всё правильно

Comment: `print(f"{variable:.8f}")` ?

Comment: @MaxU а еще можно число перевести в строку, найти количество знаков после  "." и место 8f передать нужное  количество значков после точки, чтобы не дописывало лишние нули , вот только зачем все это:)

Comment: Ну как бы место экономится такой записью ))  Используйте форматирование при выводе, если вам не нравится то, которое используется по умолчанию

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin, а вы попробуйте сделать бухгалтеру, сводящему годовой баланс, отчет с экспоненциальной записью - интересно увидеть ее/его реакцию... ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь форматированием строк. Еще удобнее воспользоваться [`f-string`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals), который стал доступен начиная с Python 3.6.

исходный вариант - форматирование по умолчанию:

```
In [52]: print(a, b, c)
3e-06 4e-06 7e-06
```

используем форматирование строк:

```
In [54]: print("{:.8f}, {:.8f}, {:.8f}".format(a,b,c))
0.00000300, 0.00000400, 0.00000700
```

используем `f-string` форматирование (обратите внимание на букву `f` перед началом строкового литерала: `f"<string_literal>"`):

```
In [53]: print(f"{a:.8f}, {b:.8f}, {c:.8f}")
0.00000300, 0.00000400, 0.00000700
```