# Проблема с преобразованием чисел

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть числа типа 0.000000023

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но по итогу они преобразовываются в 23*10^-9

Как мне сделать так, чтобы они оставались в виде 0.000000023?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как выводить числа, которые выводятся в экспоненциальной записи, в нормальном (десятичном) виде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1139092/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Формат Decimal заботится о том чтоб к числу не добавилась погрешность округления от преобразования к float

```
import decimal

decimal.Decimal('0.000000023')
decimal.Decimal(9)*decimal.Decimal(10)**-9
```

если `1` перед `e-09` не важна, то  просто используйти принт с форматированием.

```
>>> print('%.10f' % 0.000000023)
0.0000000230
>>> print('%.2f' % 12.123)
12.12
>>> print('%e' % 0.000000023)
2.300000e-08
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете избежать такого вывода с помощью `'%f' % a`, но он выдаст лишь нули, поэтому вам нужно будет вручную задать необходимую точность вывода: `'%.15f' % a`